# Is it known in what year(s) the plot of Ender's Game takes place?

Tags: books, enders-game

I just finished listening to the *Ender's Game* audiobook and I'm currently listening to *Speaker of the Dead*.
It's pretty clear that the story takes place in the future but is it known when exactly? I might have missed it but I don't remember any mention of a year or something that gives a hint in what year the book begins.
The only references I recall are about in-universe events like the *Second Invasion* which took place some 70 to 80 years before *Ender's Game*. But how long before that did the *First Invasion* take place and when? I'm not sure if this was said in the book.

*Speaker of the Dead* only confused me more when when they introduced a new calendar/timeline (before and after Starways Code).

**TL;DR - Is there any information in the books or other media that specifices or allows us to determine a timeline for the plot of Ender's Game? (matching the Gregorian calendar)**

Comment: The Shadow books might provide a date - but I won't be able to check until tomorrow night. WP at least pegs Ender's Shadow as starting "about 2170", although the synopsis for Shadows in Flight says Bean left Earth in 2210, which doesn't really fit.

Comment: @HorusKol It would be nice if you could give it a look. The movie timeline surely looks nice but I'm sceptical that it matches the timeline from the books. Assuming the Enderverse has something like a coherent timeline and Card didn't just throw arround dates in his books.

Comment: *Xenocide* ch. 2 sets the events of *Ender's Game* in the twenty-second century, which is consistent with the other dates given here.

Comment: Ender is 6 when he goes to battle school according to the original book so the answer by Phantom 42 should be sufficient.

Comment: This is more suited to a comment than an answer. Please review the site info and take a look at how other more experienced users post answers to questions. Welcome to the site.

Comment: No, it isn't. From *Jack B Nimbles* answer we can deduce that the movie timeline is probably inconsistent with the book timeline. I'm also still waiting on an answer citing source material to prove the answers as correct.That Ender was 6 both in the movie and the book when he entered Battle School doesn't mean that the dates are correct. They differ from those used in the Wiki by 40 to 60 years and we have no way of knowing which if any are correct.

Comment: Why not ask him yourself? Orson Scott Card is a gregarious member of Quora, if not other forums, and not averse to discussing his own works - provided people don't ask what they could have found out with a bit of research.

Personally, I have no idea why anyone would mind… particularly not since a lifetime ago Star Wars swapped its own futuristic everything for "long ago and far away…"

Comment: The prequel books give the year.

Answer (score 5):

I'll try to do some more digging to find out if the books specify, but Lion's Gate (the production company behind the movie) released [this timeline](http://entertainment.time.com/2013/10/24/exclusive-an-enders-game-timeline-chart/) of the events leading up to the movie.

In the movie-verse, at least, **the primary story of Ender's Game begins in 2195.**

It seems that this timeline was probably constructed based on the non-final script (based on a conflicting date of the First Invasion and Ender's apparent age at the beginning of the film).

[image: enders game timeline]

Comment: That timeline does not appear to be consistent with the movie. For instance, Ender is obviously not 6 years old when he enters Battle School. Also at the beginning of the movie it is started to be 2086 when Mazer Rackman defeats the Bugger fleet.

Comment: @JackBNimble Everything I can find states that Ender is 6 when the book begins. I haven't watched the movie yet. Are you saying that movie-Ender is "obviously not 6" when it begins?

Comment: I'm saying that the movie starts by saying it is 2086, when Mazer Rackman defeats the first invasion (I don't think there was a second invasion), it means everything on that image you posted is already wrong. The movie also has Ender as 12 when he starts battle school.

Comment: Guys, one of you is talking about the book, the other is talking about the film. Please specify explicitly in the question if you want sources from a specific material. The timeline is from the book I guess, because yes, Ender is approximatively 10-12 (maybe 13-14, but not older) in the film

Comment: @Kalissar That poster is for the movie (see just before the image in the answer), and in the movie Ender is definitely older than 6 at the beginning.  The production company made a mistake somewhere when they created that timeline.  That's what Jack's comment is about.  I'd attribute it to poor choice of actor / they couldn't wait a few years for the actor to visibly grow up over the course of the movie, though.

Comment: Is there something that affirms that the movie timeline matches the book timeline? Maybe a statement in an interview or a Making-of or something similiar?

Comment: @Sebastian_H I've been unable to find anything definitive yet, but I found a quote from Gavin Hood discussing the need to condense the time frame of the movie to avoid Ender aging through the movie - going back to the possibility that this timeline was produced off the unfinished script.

Comment: The movie certainly doesn't match the book timeline as the movie feels to take place over maybe a year or two total, with Ender being somewhere between pre to early teens. The book takes place over several years and starts with Ender as a 6 year old and ends somewhere in his mid-teens maybe (I haven't read it in a while so I can't remember exactly.). Actually I guess if you include the epilogue it ends with Ender aging into adulthood as the governor of the first colony post xenocide, but that didn't make it into the movie at all.

Comment: The movie also completely skips over the bits in the book where Valentine and Peter conquer the world by blogging.

Comment: @JackBNimble "Ender is obviously not 6 years old when he enters Battle School." The producers are obviously not going to cast a 6-year-old in this role.  This does not create a new canon. You will just have to suspend disbelief a little longer.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of anything in the books that line up the timelines to our Gregorian calendar. However, the [Enderverse Wiki has this timeline](https://enderverse.fandom.com/wiki/Enderverse_Timeline).

- circa 2060 ad - First Invasion
- circa 2080 ad - Second Invasion
- circa 2171 ad - Destruction of Bugger Homeworld
- circa 5173 ad - The events of Speaker for the Dead (extrapolated from Jane's statement that is had been 3002 years since Ender left the Solar System).

At one point it is stated that the first invasion happened roughly 100 years before Ender went to Battle School.

In the film *Ender's Game*, the First Invasion takes place in 2086 (as stated on screen). The timeline setup in the movie does not match the timeline in the books.

Comment: They state that the dates are approximate. But to give even approximate dates they would at least need something as a reference point. Unfortunately no reference point or source is given for the timeline (at least I didn't see one). Though at least subjectively it feels right that that Card would let the story take place roughly 100 years after he conceived it.

Comment: The linked Wiki page has been deleted. Is there any more canonical source?

Comment: -1: Suspect calculations, because the Ender's Game Wiki actually works with their own BX/AX timeline, where X is the destruction of the Formic homeworld in the climatic scene of Ender's Game. According to their scale: 2118CE (or AD if you prefer)=97BX (taken from the Swarm), so X, the destruction of the Formic homeworld is in 2215, the first invasion 2115, Ender landing on Lusitania in Speaker of the Dead is ~3000AX or ~5215CE Gregorian

Answer (score 0):

The original series had no direct references to the Gregorian calendar.

The Second Formic Wars book The Swarm have the date of 2118AD for the events of that book (quoted in a note in chapter 2) which take place approximately 92 years before the start of the novel Ender's Game (or 97 years before the destruction of the Formic home world). That would place the destruction of the Formic homeworld around 2223AD.

But Shadows in flight has Bean's ship leaving Earth in 2210AD,

**Opening Line: **
The starship Herodotus left Earth in 2210 with four passengers

This is supposedly 8 years after the last battle which would put the destruction of the Formic home world at 2202AD. Those two dates are the only ones I can find and they don't match up. So the best we can guess is Ender's Game takes place somewhere between 2200 and 2225AD.

The books The Hive Queen and The Hegemon are supposedly published 41 years after the last battle in Ender's Game, and the Starways Congress founding happens somewhere after that.

From Speaker for the Dead, the colonisation of Lusitania is in 1886SC and Ender/Andrew arrives on Lusitania 1970SC, supposedly around 3002 years after the ending of Ender's Game, which would be either around 5204 or 5225AD depending on which of the aforementioned references you use, which would place the SC year 0 as either 3234 or 3255AD.

That's as close as I can guess it.

The SC dating in the books end up giving conflicting info too, because the founding is moved from around 60 years after the battle to something like 600 years after.

So anyway, given the 21 year discrepancy, which really isn't much given the 3000+ year time span, you can use the arrival at Lusitania to calculate other stuff in the timeline.

**Edit: **
That whole attempt above at finding the answers is actually obsolete. The people at the Enderverse Wiki did a much more thorough job of setting up a timeline.
You can check it out here: https://enderverse.fandom.com/wiki/Enderverse_Timeline

I will put a quick timeline based on their calcs in a new answer

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, but it would be a great answer if you could provide actual quotes from the books you reference showing the exact inconsistencies

Comment: Well, for the first date, at the start of chapter two of The Swarm, there's a quoted message from the strategos to the hegemon which is followed by its origin (location and date) : Luna, May 12, 2118. I can't remember where else in the book, would have to go through and check. This is supposed to be after first invasion and before the start of the second. Shadows in Flight chapter 1 starts: "The starship Herodotus left Earth in 2210 with four passengers" then skips ahead 5 ship years or 421 earth years. That help?

Comment: As a side note: continuity, what continuity? Every book published after the original Ender's Game had some stuff contradicting what happened before. It doesn't exactly help that Ender's Game itself was re-written and that the1991 version doesn't have the same "history" as the original.

Comment: yeah, stuff like that. Editing it into the answer though is what I meant. As for continuity problems, just make a note in your answer about major ones and I'd just use the most recent version of Ender's Game for any dates/timelines

Comment: Where do you get the numbers 92 and 97 from?

Comment: @ibid Basically from Ender's game. Mazer Racham's explanation of how he got t be there to teach Ender, and from The Swarm

Comment: @Gwyn - All that's said in that conversation in EG about the passage of time is "*You fought your battle seventy years ago.*". I don't see how get from that to 97 years.

Comment: @ibid In the conversation with Graff on the way to Eros, they say the first invasion was a hundred years ago, and Ender's been at the battle school for over three years by then, so 97 when he started. When Ender is studying the battle videos at battle school, they mention that the second was 80 years ago. Or 82 by the time the the coversation with Rackam takes place. Rackham's battle ending that was 70 years ago at that point. But then when the prequels started coming out a lot of discrepancies started creeping in ...

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to but a clearer timeline than my previous answer.

Note that the original books had no reference to the Gregorian calendar. There was only an internal timeline, with only references to how long ago certain things happened. Later books such as the Formic Wars and Shadows series books did have references to the Gregorian calendar.

**According to the Ender's Game Wiki:**

If you set the year 0 or X as the destruction of the Formic homeworld in Ender's Game, some of the key events are as follows:

- 100 BX (2115)
  First Formic War
- 95 BX  (2120)
  Second Formic War
- 11 BX  (2204)
  Ender Wiggin born
- Year  0X (2215)
  Third Formic War, Formic world destroyed,
  Ender leaves solar system
- 8 AX  (2223)
  Bean's ship leaves solar system
- 41 AX  (2256)
  The Hive Queen published
- 3000 AX (5215) (1970SC)
  Andrew arrives on Lusitania
  Events of Speaker for the Dead

Note: this places the founding of Starways Congress and the year 0 of the Starways calendar as ~1030 AX or 3245 (Gregorian).

They also use the events of  *The Swarm* from the second Formic Wars (2118CE) to tie the Gregorian calendar to their own rather than *Shadows in Flight* and Andrew's landing on Lusitania to tie in the SC calendar) and note that the ~3000 years between the destruction of the Formic homeworld and the events of SotD as mentioned in the book is most probably an estimate, but is the only reference to be had in order to tie the three calendars together.

You can check out the rest of the timeline here: https://enderverse.fandom.com/wiki/Enderverse_Timeline